# "Product Type is invalid or not supported in rows" importing csv file

Tags: csv, database, upload

I’m new in using Magento.

I’m using Magento 1.9. My web site have to sell Paper books and Ebooks, so I set two kind of products in my catalogue: “simple” and “downloadable”. Now my need is to import automatically with a csv (or xml) file all my catalogue. But when I use the import function it works just for “simple product”.

When I import a csv file like this:

*sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites,title_book […other attributes]
123456,,"paper books",**simple**,"Paper books","My category",base,"My paper book title" […other values]*

Everything works fine. If I change the type value in downloadable, with something like the following:

*sku,_store,_attribute_set,_type,_category,_root_category,_product_websites,title_book […other attributes]
123456E,,"ebooks",**downloadable**,"Ebooks"," My category ",base, ,"My ebook title" […other values]*

I get the following message error:
**Product Type is invalid or not supported in rows**

I tried to import with *System>Import/Export/Import* root or using the *Dataflow Profiles* both.

If I change the type value in **grouped** or **virtual** or **configurable** it works. The problem is just for downloadable one.

It’s making me crazy!

Can someone help me, please?

Thank you,
Enzo

EDIT:

And is there a suggestion on how modify the ImportExport config file? I would just need to upload the metadata of my product (the same attributes that I use for my simple products). My will is to add the files manually after the upload of csv file.

Answer (score 6):

As of CE 1.9.0.1, only four product types can be imported using ImportExport:

- Simple
- Configurable
- Virtual
- Grouped

These types and their import models are defined in the [ImportExport config file](https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror/blob/ace81acc583ece32317a785eab3e24aaad124a7c/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/etc/config.xml#L94).

I'm afraid you would have to write your own import adapter for downloadable products.